# Reading CSV files that are tab delimited

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a CSV file in python that has tabs as a seperator by doing this:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('data', sep='\t')
```

However, the dataframe only returns rows with 1 column, seperating the different columns and values with a ";". How can I get a dataframe that is similar to the CSV file with the seperated columns by tabs?

Comment: Can you give an example line which you try to read?

Comment: Are you sure the `data` file uses tab and not `;`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments, the data looks like this:

https://gyazo.com/5b93bde31c4f356fdf88e30e766c40e3

returning this: https://gyazo.com/453594b496af5d025c37fbc9e30526c5

Comment: Try with : `sep=';'`

Comment: That works indeed, thank you! Any idea why it is ';' in this case?

Comment: You can change the delimiter type from the program you are using to open/edit the csv